# Why do different implementations of AES produce different output?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I feel I have a pretty good understanding of hash functions and the contracts they entail.

SHA1 on Input X will ALWAYS produce the same output.  You could use a Python library, a Java library, or pen and paper.  It's a function, it is deterministic.  My SHA1 does the same as yours and Alice's and Bob's.

As I understand it, AES is also a function.  You put in some values, it spits out the ciphertext.

Why, then, could there ever be fears that Truecrypt (for instance) is "broken"?  They're not saying AES is broken, they're saying the program that implements it may be.  AES is, in theory, solid.  So why can't you just run a file through Truecrypt, run it through a "reference AES" function, and verify that the results are the same?  I know it absolutely does not work like that, but I don't know why.

What makes AES different from SHA1 in this way?  Why might Truecrypt AES spit out a different file than Schneier-Ifier* AES, when they were both given all the same inputs?

In the end, my question boils down to:

My_SHA1(X) == Bobs_SHA1(X) == ...etc

But TrueCrypt_AES(X) != HyperCrypt_AES(X) != VeraCrypt_AES(X) etc.  Why is that?  Do all those programs wrap AES, but have different ways of determining stuff like an initialization vector or something?

*this would be the name of my file encryption program if I ever wrote one

Comment: If the implementations are properly test with test vectors, then they are interoperable with other implementations. AES itself is only a miniscule part of Truecrypt.

Comment: Basically, yes, the "or something" is correct :) Note that for a cipher to CPA secure, it is *required* that you get different ciphertext even for identical plaintext. This feat can only performed by giving AES something unique during encryption. That's where the IV comes in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the SHA-1 example you give, there is only a single input to the function, and any correct SHA-1 implementation should produce the same output as any other when provided the same input data.

For AES however things are a bit tricker, and since you don't specify what you mean exactly by "AES", this itself seems likely to be the source of the *perceived* differences between implementations.

Firstly, "AES" isn't a single algorithm, but a family of algorithms that take different **key sizes** (128, 192 or 256 bits). AES is also a block cipher, it takes a single block of 128 bits/16 bytes of **plaintext** input, and encrypts this using the key to produce a single 16 byte block of output.

Of course in practice we often want to encrypt more than 16 bytes of data at once, so we must find a way to repeatedly apply the AES algorithm in order to encrypt all the data. Naively we could split it into 16 byte chunks and encrypt each one in turn, but this mode (described as Electronic Codebook or ECB) turns out to be [horribly insecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29). Instead, various other more secure **[modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)** are usually used, and most of these require an **Initialization Vector (IV)** which helps to ensure that encrypting the same data with the same key doesn't result in the same ciphertext (which would otherwise leak information).

Most of these modes still operate on fixed-sized blocks of data, but again we often want to encrypt data that isn't a multiple of the block size, so we have to use some form of **[padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography))**, and again there are various different possibilities for how we pad a message to a length that is a multiple of the block size.

So to put all of this together, two different implementations of "AES" should produce the same output if *all* of the following are identical:

- Plaintext input data
- Key (and hence key size)
- IV
- Mode (including any mode-specific inputs)
- Padding

Comment: tl;dr version: Truecrypt is a _cryptosystem_, of which the cipher is only a small part. There are many ways a cryptosystem can be broken even if its components are secure.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  So does this mean that, under the pretense that the AES specification is secure, all the INSECURITIES of a system like TrueCrypt come from how TrueCrypt derives the IV or does padding?  If TrueCrypt is just one big wrapper for some AES(args...) function, and AES(args...) is secure, it must be that TrueCrypt is insecurely picking args?

Comment: @andy - yes, as the other commenter said, it's easy to build an insecure cryptosystem even when using a secure basic algorithm such as AES. The Wikipedia example for ECB in my answer gives a good example of this. There are plenty of other trivial examples of ways to weaken a cryptosytem, e.g. using the same IV every time.

Answer (score 1):

Iridium covered many of the causes for a different output between TrueCrypt and other programs using nominally the same (AES) algorithm.  If you are just checking actual initialization vectors, these tend to be done using ECB.  It is the only good time to use ECB -- to make sure the algorithm itself is implemented correctly.  This is because ECB, while insecure, does work without an IV and therefore makes it easier to check "apples to apples" though other stumbling blocks remain as Iridium pointed out.

With a test vector, the key is specified along with the plain text.  And test vectors are specified as exact multiples of the block size.  Or more specifically, they tend to be exactly 1 block in size for the plain text.  This is done to remove padding and mode from the list of possible differences.  So if you use standard test vectors between two AES encryption programs, you eliminate the issue with the plain text data differences, key differences, IV, mode, and padding.

But note you can still have differences.  AES is just as deterministic as hashing, so you can get the same result every time with AES just as you can with hashing.  It's just that there are more variables to control to get the same output result.  One item Iridium did not mention but which can be an issue is endianness of the input (key and plain text).  I ran into exactly this when checking a reference implementation of Serpent against TrueCrypt.  They gave the same output to the text vectors *only* if I reversed the key and plain text between them.

To elaborate on that, if you have plain text that is all 16 bytes as 0s, and your key is 31 bytes of 0s and one byte of '33' (in the 256 bit version), if the '33' byte was on the left end of the byte string for the reference implementation, you had to feed TrueCrypt 31 '00' bytes and then the '33' byte on the right-hand side to get the same output.  So as I mentioned, an endianness issue.

As for TrueCrypt maybe not being secure even if AES still is, that is absolutely true.  I don't know the specifics on TrueCrypt's alleged weaknesses, but let me present a couple ways a program can have AES down right and still be insecure.

One way would be if, after the user keys in their password, the program stores it for the session in an insecure manner.  If it is not encrypted in memory or if it encrypts your key using its own internal key but fails to protect that key well enough, you can have Windows write it out on the hard drive plain for all to read if it swaps memory to the hard drive.  Or as such swaps are less common than they used to be, unless the TrueCrypt authors protect your key during a session, it is also possible for a malicious program to come and "debug" the key right out of the TrueCrypt software.  All without AES being broken at all.

Another way it could be broken (theoretically) would be in a way that makes timing attacks possible.  As a simple example, imagine a very basic crypto that takes your 32 bit key and splits it into 2 each chunks of 16 bytes.  It then looks at the first chunk by byte.  It bit-rotates the plain text right a number of bits corresponding to the value of byte 0 of your key.  Then it XORs the plain text with the right-hand 16 bytes of your key.  Then it bit-rotates again per byte 1 of your key.  And so on, 16 shifts and 16 XORs.  Well, if a "bad guy" were able to monitor your CPU's power consumption, they could use side channel attacks to time the CPU and / or measure its power consumption on a per-bit-of-the-key basis.  The fact is it would take longer (usually, depending on the code that handles the bit-rotate) to bit-rotate 120 bits than it takes to bit-rotate 121 bits.  That difference is tiny, but it is there and it has been proven to leak key information.  The XOR steps would probably not leak key info, but half of your key would be known to an attacker with ease based on the above attack, even on an implementation of an unbroken algorithm, if the implementation itself is not done right -- a very difficult thing to do.

So I do not know if TrueCrypt is broken in one of these ways or in some other way altogether.  But crypto is a lot harder than it looks.  If the people on the inside say it is broken, it is very easy for me to believe them.