# NPM Crypto-js and PHP encryption decryption?

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I am using [crypto js node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) for angular 2 as below:

```
 var data = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
      
      // Encrypt 
      var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("My Text", 'PasswortPassword');
      console.log(ciphertext.toString());
      
      // Decrypt 
      var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, 'PasswortPassword');
      var decryptedData = (bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
      
      console.log(decryptedData);
```

And I am Using PHP backend for APIs

```
$Pass = "PasswortPassword";
$Clear = "My Text";

$crypted = fnEncrypt($Clear, $Pass);
echo "Encrypred: ".$crypted."</br>";

$newClear = fnDecrypt('U2FsdGVkX19MGni6xAIr66K/zPgDPM0thb50tUHMe8s=', $Pass);
echo "Decrypred: ".$newClear."</br>";

function fnEncrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
  return rtrim(
      base64_encode(
          mcrypt_encrypt(
              MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
              $sSecretKey, $sValue,
              MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
              mcrypt_create_iv(
                  mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                      MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                      MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                  ),
                  MCRYPT_RAND)
              )
          ), "\0"
      );
}

function fnDecrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
  return rtrim(
      mcrypt_decrypt(
          MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
          $sSecretKey,
          base64_decode($sValue),
          MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
          mcrypt_create_iv(
              mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                  MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                  MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
              ),
              MCRYPT_RAND
          )
      ), "\0"
  );
}
```

Now both the front-end and back-end needs to be on the same page for both encryption and decryption. But unfortunately, it's not the case.

I also tried to implement the code below

```
  class encryption{

    const KEY = "PasswortPassword";
    const KEY_TYPE = 'A*';

    function __construct(){
      $this->key = pack(encryption::KEY_TYPE, encryption::KEY);
      $this->key_size =  strlen($this->key);
      //echo "Key size: " . $this->key_size . "\n";
      $this->iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
      $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    }

    function encrypt($data_string){
      $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key, $data_string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $this->iv);
      $ciphertext = $this->iv . $ciphertext;

      # encode the resulting cipher text so it can be represented by a string
      $ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);

      return $ciphertext_base64;
    }

    function decrypt($data_string){
      $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($data_string);

      # retrieves the IV, iv_size should be created using mcrypt_get_iv_size()
      $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $this->iv_size);

      # retrieves the cipher text (everything except the $iv_size in the front)
      $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $this->iv_size);

      # may remove 00h valued characters from end of plain text
      $plaintext_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);

      return  $plaintext_dec;
    }

  }

  $obj = new encryption();
  echo $obj->encrypt("My Text").'<br>';

  $obj2 = new encryption();
  echo $obj2->decrypt($obj->encrypt("My Text"));
```

And to my surprise, all these 3 codes are not in sync. I get different hash values in all 3 scenarios for the same salt and sample text.

> **Question:** What is wrong with these AES codes?
>
> **Question:** How do I configure them to be in sync?
>
> **Question:** Is there any other possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at some of the suggestions here to see if they apply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737661/why-do-different-implementations-of-aes-produce-different-output

Comment: You're using ECB in Javascript and CBC in PHP. Change the JS to CBC, because if you're using ECB it might as well be plaintext. Also mcrypt is dead and has been removed from PHP7, so you should get used to using OpenSSL.

Comment: Also, Rijndael-256 is NOT AES, and mcrypt is abandonware.